# Error ORA-12154:could not resolve the connect identifier specified, en configuración de FluentNHibernate

Tags: .net, oracle, nhibernate

Descargue una solución que ya esta en ambiente de producción, del servidor a mi pc. Sin embargo al ejecutarla me muestra un error de tipo FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException:

```
{"An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.\r\n\r\n"}
```

Un InnerException con:

```
{"ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified\n"}
```

Y una traza de error así:

```
en FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
en PROYECTO_DATOS.SessionFactorySingleton.BuildSessionFactory(IPersistenceConfigurer configurer) en c:\PROYECTO\PROYECTO_DATOS\db\SessionFactorySingleton.cs:línea 88
en PROYECTO_DATOS.SessionFactorySingleton.StartSessionFactoryHash() en c:\PROYECTO\PROYECTO_DATOS\db\SessionFactorySingleton.cs:línea 67
en PROYECTO_DATOS.SessionFactorySingleton..ctor() en c:\PROYECTO\PROYECTO_DATOS\db\SessionFactorySingleton.cs:línea 34
en PROYECTO_DATOS.SessionFactorySingleton.Init() en c:\PROYECTO\PROYECTO_DATOS\db\SessionFactorySingleton.cs:línea 39
en PROYECTO.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) en c:\PROYECTO\Global.asax.cs:línea 11
```

La configuración del oracle esta hecha con FluentNHibernate, como se ve:

```
class ConfigOracle
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public IPersistenceConfigurer Configurar { get; set; }

    public ConfigOracle(string key, string connectionString)
    {
        Key = key;
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
        Configurar = OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(ConnectionString).Driver<OracleClientDriver>().ShowSql();

    }
}
```

El error se presenta en esta parte de mi codigo, despues de haber debugueado el código del mapeo de tablas.

```
private ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory(IPersistenceConfigurer configurer)
    {
        var config =
            Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(configurer)
                    .Mappings(x =>
                    {
                        x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<clase1Map>();
                        x.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<casle2Map>();
                    });

        return config.BuildSessionFactory(); <--- La ejecución se detiene aquí
    }
```

Me parece que el problema es que no encuentra el tns_name.ora de mi maquina para lograr la conexión.

Intente agregar la variable de entorno **TNS_ADMIN** con la ruta del tnsname.ora pero no dio resultado.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad, te sugiero agregar tu código ya que no esta clara tu pregunta, de lo contrario tendrá que ser cerrada.

Comment: La pregunta si es clara, pero falta que coloques tu archivo hibernate.cfg.xml y la traza de error completa.

Comment: tienes instalado el ODAC en la pc ? porque cuando el error es que no puede resolver el tns es porque faltan los driver de Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Se solvento el problema. La aplicación se conecta a varias bases de datos por lo que empece a comparar las cadenas de conexión que estan definidas en la **aplicación** contra las que están definidas en el **tns_name.ora de mi pc** y lo que faltaba era definir una de ellas en el **tns_name.ora**.